# Proteus PCB component size changes when rotated

Tags: proteus

[image: This is before rotation][[image: this one is after rotation ][1]]

I'm doing PCB layout in Proteus, why does it look like the size of the component change when I place and rotate it?

Comment: I'm not seeing the size difference, can you point it out?  Adding the shots to the question was the right way to go.

Comment: Wild guess: is your monitor set to an aspect ratio other than its native aspect ratio? Because the size doesn't look different here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those sizes look exactly the same to me. If I count the grid squares, they seem to be the same size that way too: about 11 grid squares in the longer dimension, and between 8 and 9 grid squares in the shorter dimension.

The most likely cause is that the pixels on your computer monitor are not square, so you're seeing a distorted picture of what Proteus is trying to show you. There should be a way to adjust your monitor settings so that you see things correctly. If you try different screen resolutions, you should be able to find one that makes the squares look square.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I just noticed that it has to do with my computer resolution.  I tried to see the same drawing on my phone and it showed the undistorted components.